# texture paint, only part of the mesh is paintable?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm super frustrated with this one, I've spent a lot of time on the mesh, got the uv's layed out all nice, and now when i go to paint it, it only lets me paint part of the sleeves. What am I doing wrong? I'd rather edit in photoshop so is there a way to just fill the uvs? I tried exporting the uv's and nothing showed up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the file you uploaded the image "yfbody.dds" doesn't exist. After creating a new image to replace "yfbody.dds" I am able to paint onto the model.

When exporting UV's you either need to select all the UV's you want included or turn on the All UV's option.